# Use the rename function to modify multiple parts of a filename?

Tags: windows, command-line, rename, batch-rename, windows-client

I've got the following pattern :

[AAAAAA] **Title - 1234** (AAAAAA)[Something that changes].mkv

I'd like to only keep :
**Title - 1234**

The *AAAAAA* parts are always the same : 10 letters for the first set, and 4 numbers + 1 letter for the second set.

The *Title - 1234* part changes constantly.
The *[Something that changes]* part changes constantly.

Is there a way to remove what's before ] and after (, so that I only keep the Title and the Episode n° ?

I don't mind making multiple "rename" commands (I do that in batch anyway)

Any way to do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: The `AAAAAA` part - is it always consecutive six letters?

Comment: Actually no, it was more of an example ^^" ! The first part is always 10 letters long, just didn't put the whole thing as it would've been long to read x)

Comment: & the second part that never changes (AAAAA) is made of 4 numbers + 1 letter at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this string substitute:

This find the first "]" and trim everything from beginning
Then trim all after the first "("

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%F in (*.mkv) do (
   set "f=%%~F"
   set "f=!f:*]=!"
   call :trim
   echo ren "%%~F" "!f!%%~xF"
)

pause
goto :eof

:trim
SET f=%f:(=&rem.%
goto :eof
```

output:

```
C:\Users\fposc\AppData\Local\Temp>ren1
ren "[AAAAAA] Title - 1234 (AAAAAA)[Something that changes].mkv" " Title - 1234 .mkv"
Premere un tasto per continuare . . .
```

---

If you want to remove leading and trailing spaces you can include them in the code like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%F in (*.mkv) do (
   set "f=%%~F"
   set "f=!f:*] =!"
   call :trim
   echo ren "%%~F" "!f!%%~xF"
)

pause
goto :eof

:trim
SET f=%f: (=&rem.%
goto :eof
```

output:

```
C:\Users\fposc\AppData\Local\Temp>ren1
ren "[AAAAAA] Title - 1234 (AAAAAA)[Something that changes].mkv" "Title - 1234.mkv"
Premere un tasto per continuare . . .
```

Test this and when is ok you can remove the "echo" and left "ren" command or copy the output in a file and then execute.

Comment: Yes, it worked as perfection !! Thank you ! Hero !

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-replace` regex operator:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mkv |Rename-Item -NewName {"$($_.BaseName -replace '^\[\p{L}{10}\]\s*([^\(]+).*$','$1').mkv"}
```

The pattern used

```
^\[\p{L}{10}\]\s*([^\(]+).*$
```

... matches:

```
^              # Start of string
 \[            # Literal `[`
 \p{L}{10}     # 10 consecutive letters
 \]            # Literal `]`
 \s*           # Any whitespace
 ([^\(]+)      # Capture the longest possible sequence on non-`(` chars
 .*            # the rest of the string (eg. `(ABCD1) something something.mkv`)
$              # End of string
```

We then replace the whole thing with everything we captured in between the `]` and `(`.

Comment: Thanks ! One question though : is it not possible to do it via cmd with the rename function ? I'm asking that cause I plan on using it as part of a batch file (.bat) so I'd rather avoid having to launch powershell everytime (unless it's the only option) ^^"

Comment: @SamoussaBinouMymusicisinme I'm afraid I wouldn't know how to do it in cmd/batch :)